# getting questions and answers in 1 single query

Tags: sql, database

I need to make a query that fetches all the users questions and for every question, 3 answers from the database. This query needs to be as efficient as possible.

I have the tables:

```
questions:
  id
  user_id
  title
  date_created
  date_updated

answers:
  id
  question_id
  user_id
  body
  date_created
```

Can I do it in 1 single query? Basically I need to display the question, to make a join with users table to get the username, display 3 answers for the question and show for each answer the username of the poster.

What I dit is something like this:

```
SELECT questions.*, GROUP_CONCAT(answers.id) as answers 
  FROM (questions) 
  JOIN users ON users.id = questions.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id 
 WHERE questions.user_id = '1' 
 GROUP BY questions.id 
 ORDER BY questions.date_updated desc 
 LIMIT 3
```

But this is not finished and also is not working well.

Comment: I'm thinking there is a way to avoid `GROUP_CONCAT` ... and that you should.  :-)

Comment: i tried group concat to make 1 query...because i have a user with many questions and a question with many answers

Comment: The requirement to include username with the answer-text makes use of `CONCAT` problematic.  And, there is a more natural way:  you can query inside a query.  This would still be called "a single query," I expect.

Comment: Which row  in the answers table is the answer stored in?

Comment: I notice that question ID is not in your question table. In your question table, is your ID feild the question ID? I would fix that if I where you. It's bad practice to not give the foreign key the same name as the primary key it is related to.

Comment: What DBMS software are you targeting? eg SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a cross apply... it depdens on what version of SQL server you are using but here is a sample query.

use a outer apply if your not sure if the question has answers
use cross apply if you only want questions with answers

```
SELECT
  q.id,
   q.[user_id],
   q.title,
   q.date_created,
   q.date_updated,
   ans.id,
   ....
FROM
  questions q
     CROSS APPLY
     (
     SELECT TOP 3
        a.id,
       a.question_id,
       a.[user_id],
       a.body,
       a.date_created
     FROM
       answers a
     WHERE
       q.id = a.question_id
     ) ans
```

[see more here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming title is the question and body is the answer, and that for some weird reason the id field in the question table is related to question id in the answers table. To limit three answers, you may want to create a subquery.

```
SELECT title, FROM questions 
WHERE user_id IN 
(SELECT users.username, answers.body FROM users, answers WHERE 
 answers.user_id = users.user_id LIMIT 3);
```

However I would fix the fact that question_id is called id in your question table, it's very bad practice to not give the foreign key the same name as the primary key it is related to.

Comment: How is that very bad practice? It may be against your organizations coding standards, but it's not bad practice from a general standpoint. It's certainly not always possible to have a FK always have the same name, For example in an Employee Table you might want to put the Employees supervisor, which is another EmployeeID

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your database design to this:

```
post:
  id
  parent_id
  user_id
  title
  date_created
  date_updated
```

In this design questions have a NULL parent_id. Now you can make a query like this:

```
select posts.* from
(
    SELECT id, parent_id, user_id, title, date_created, date_updated FROM post WHERE id = 67
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, parent_id, NULL as user_id, NULL as title, NULL as date_created, NULL as date_updated FROM post WHERE parent_id = 67
) posts
Left JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id
WHERE posts.user_id = '1' 
ORDER BY posts.date_updated desc 
LIMIT 3
```

Make sure NULL parent_id is first when you pull data from the database so the question is in the first position. This way it is much faster, managable and has more readability.